# grub problem with m2 ssd

Tags: grub2, ssd, m2

I have a simple installation: /dev/sda is a ssd /dev/sdb is an ordinary hdd.
I have multiple system on my sda: Window 10, UbuntuMate 16.4 and UbuntuMate 18.4.
Now i add a new M2-SSD. I would like to an a third UbuntuMate 18.04. While installing everything works fine. No error messages. The boot-loader always on /dev/sda.
When i reboot my system, i only get an GRUB> prompt. After repairing the grub over my existing UbuntuMate 18.04, i get a complete list of all System (Win10, 3xUbuntu).
But if i select the new system on my M2-SSD i get the following error:
"no such device: "
"please load /boot/vmlinux...generic first"

grub.cfg contains this:

menuentry 'Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (18.04) (auf /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-69b68811-037a-4086-ad35-8d8c0282a327' {

```
insmod part_gpt

insmod ext2

if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then

  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  69b68811-037a-4086-ad35-8d8c0282a327

else

  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 69b68811-037a-4086-ad35-8d8c0282a327

fi

linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic root=UUID=69b68811-037a-4086-ad35-8d8c0282a327 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff

initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
```

}

and lsblk shows this:

nvme0n1

├─nvme0n1p1

│       ext4                       69b68811-037a-4086-ad35-8d8c0282a327

├─nvme0n1p2

│       ext4                       4819bb70-9f21-4e61-94b2-2a752d78c6ad

└─nvme0n1p3

```
    ext4                       868973fc-2f62-4761-b3ee-20e367801511
```

i thing everythink look ok, but it does't work.

Have anybody an idea?

Thanks
Rüdiger.